# Toast Error , xOffsets-yOffsets problem Toast Problem

Tags: java, android, android-toast

**Hello Friends I hope all will be well**
Dear brothers i have been facing an error of offset in simple gravity toast
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDZUy.png)

Comment: This is fairly easy to get . a get method returns the value and set method set the value ..

Comment: Please check [ask]. Do not post greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use setGravity method**

```
Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```